# How to create a valid request through the eBay trading API and AddItem in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I have already looked through documentation on both GitHub for the SDK and on the official eBay docs. On the GitHub, it appears that the dictionary in one of the samples is outdated. I tried to use a library to convert the XML from the eBay forum under "Sample: Basic Call" (https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/additem.html#Samples) but I get the same error when making an API call (that an attribute or multiple are missing). I've tried copying the dictionary structure from multiple places but it always ends up returning that an an element is missing.

```
from ebaysdk.trading import Connection

myitem = {}         # here I have the dict converted from XML
api = Connection(config_file="ebay.yaml", domain="api.sandbox.ebay.com")
api.execute("VerifyAddItem", myitem)               # VerifyAddItem same problem as AddItem
```

As for the error it comes in the form of something like

```
ebaysdk.exception.ConnectionError: 'VerifyAddItem: Class: RequestError, Severity: Error, Code: 10009, No <Item.Currency> exists or <Item.Currency> is specified as an empty tag. No <Item.Currency> exists or <Item.Currency> is specified as an empty tag in the request., Class: RequestError, Severity: Error, Code: 10009, No <Item.Country> exists or <Item.Country> is specified as an empty tag. No <Item.Country> exists or <Item.Country> is specified as an empty tag in the request., Class: RequestError, Severity: Error, Code: 10009, No <Item.ListingDuration> exists or <Item.ListingDuration> is specified as an empty tag. No <Item.ListingDuration> exists or <Item.ListingDuration> is specified as an empty tag in the request.'
```

You can replace the <Item.*Name*> with whatever tag is missing depending on how I have tried to fix the problem.

The GitHub example item I found (https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python/blob/master/samples/trading.py `myitem`) gave the same problem (with a different tag) which is why I thought it might be outdated (example was committed 3 years ago).

Also, I am using the old APIs because I don't know how (or if) you can create single listings with the REST APIs.

Answer (score 0):

using a SDK can help avoiding some steps, but to make a successful call you have to understand how the `API` works and carefully read the documentation.

in the github example, are stated 3 `SellerProfiles` with their own names:
but you need to create them before making the call elsewhere it will return an error.

Beside this, in recent years several nodes has been added and other, like `Brand`, `MPN`, `ItemSpecifics` and other has switched to "Required".

Furthermore `ItemSpecifics` list (yes are several nodes) depends on the `PrimaryCategory/CategoryID`, some are required, some other suggested and other optional.

Again, most fields do not accept free text but do have a list of suggested/required values

Needless to say that to get the list of `ItemSpecifics` you need to call another `API`.

The cherry on top is that for "OLD Trading API" the call to get `ItemSpecifics` list has been decommissioned, and therefore need to use the new REST API.

Finally, concerning `SDK`... sdk often avoids to reinvent the wheel..
but if it's a wooden wheel...

Comment: Can I use REST API to get the itemspecifics then use that in the old API? Also is there anyway to not use SDK that is not overly complex? I haven't found much on using python as a google search will return guides/docs but its for the SDK. I will look through the code on the gitHub example more and see if it helps at all.

Comment: Not used the REST API to get ItemSpecifics yet, but all APIs, old and new refer to the same DataBase, therefore the values should be the same.
eBay is a complex marketplace with hundreds of options, therefore there is no simple solution.

Comment: So is the best option for me to go and copy XML into a python dictionary format?

Comment: Personally I build the XML in the SQL Server Stored Procedure, but I do not know which can be the best option for you: it depends on the project, the target, the skills and many other parameters. That said, although there are simple function to convert the 2 formats, using a py dictionary that is basically a json file, for an XML payload would not be my first option.

Comment: Is there a way to just use XML with the api? I think the SDK only takes dict so i'd need to directly call the api? Do you know anywhere I can look to try that out.

Comment: `API` payload is just `XML` and all APIs works with `HTTP Requests`.
Among `eBay` documentation there's almost all you need, then you can search google to learn how `HTTP Request` works in your preferred language.
But do not expect to succeed in 1 or 2 days.

Comment: Ok I will try using HTTP. I know how to do that in my language. However, when I go to ebay dev site it says HTTP will soon lose support?